# RegExp part of string TO specific letter (not including)

Tags: regex, string, csv, split, notepad++

**Is there a way to select a part of a string up to a letter but not getting the letter in the result ?**

e.g Samplestring

```
1111111111;aaaaaaaaa;12ab12ab12
```

In the End I want to achive some like a splitstring

```
1111111111
aaaaaaaaaa
12ab12ab12
```

I had a lot of tries... atm im along with `^(.*?)` to get the first part...

but I still want to get rid of the semicolon.

***Im trying this in notepad++***

**EDIT:**

I want to edit a File with 9k lines and replace some stuff

```
1111111111;aaaaaaaaa;12ab12ab12
```

should end up in e.g.

```
update table set x=1111111111, y='aaaaaaaaa' where z='12ab12ab12';
```

on notepad++ replace there should be some like

```
update table set x='\3', y='\2' where z=\1;
```

Comment: How about matching `[^;]+`

Comment: that looks goot @anubhava. I will try this.. may add an answere and if this helps, i would accapt this :)

Comment: ah.. thats not 100%... but this may helps... i will test a bit more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use capture groups to capture the parts you want to rearrange, and reluctant quantifiers:

```
Find: ^(.*?);(.*?);(.*)
Repl: update table set x='$1', y='$2' where z=$3;
```

FYI `.*?` matches as *little* as possible and is more efficient than `.*`.

---

Note: From comments you've made, it seems you must have checked the ". matches newline" option (bottom of the find/replace dialog box next to "Regular expressions" option). Unless you understand and want this behaviour, it's usually best not to check this.

Comment: funny :) i just found out almost the same :D `^(.*?);(.*?);(.*?)\r\n` BUUUUT, i still have to add `\r\n`otherwise its still 1 match...

Comment: @dwza actually, I just realised that in this case you can just use plain old `.*`

Comment: `^(.*?);(.*?);(.*?)\r\n` is the only what where every row is involved. at least npp says now xx rows effected

Comment: @dwza Then there's something weird about your file. Anyway `.*?` is more efficient :)

Comment: its a simple plain txt file... for testing i only have 12 rows... npp version 6.8.6

Comment: anyway.,... if my file is strange or not... at the end this was the right solution, even if i had the same idea in the same moment :) thank you anyways

Comment: Do you have ". matches newline" option ticked? I think you must have it ticked.

Answer (score 0):

Just tried this by select `Regular Expression' in Replace tab and it worked

`Find what` `;`

`Replace with` `\n`

Comment: since i have 9k lines... this might be not the best idea :D